# Why doesn't Tesseract recognize a simple word?

Tags: tesseract

I am experimenting with Tesseract and failed already on the second attempt.

Here is the image file:

[image]

The result is always an empty string. The code looks as follows:

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string

image_file = Image.open('image.png')
print(image_to_string(image_file))
```

I tried also directly from terminal

> tesseract image.png out

again with no success.

Is there something wrong with this image or am I doing something wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Tesseract installed with apt-get as well as pytesseract installed using pip.

Python version : 3.4

Comment: I also get no result with the original image. When the original image is cropped before feeding tesseract to not contain much paddings surrounding the text, the result of tesseract is 100% almost always.  I can't tell exactly why it works such way but assuming that the background colours and texture may confuse the preprocessing phase. I would suggest to have a segmentation algorithm before feeding tesseract. Will add additional information after having explanation why exactly it doesn't work with your image.

Answer (score 0):

After applying a grayscale or monochrome filter, it produced "DDownload!".

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/ocr/tesseract.html) document I found interesting link to these [advices](https://www.howtoforge.com/ocr_with_tesseract_on_ubuntu704) which should be helpful. Look at section "4 Prepare Images" in the advices page.

> A more advanced OCR program would do this itself. No doubt Tesseract
>   will improve.